# For any inner product, can we always find a symmetric orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Given an inner product space $(V,<>)$ where $V$ is a vector space. Denote the scalar field of $V$ as $F$, define an inner product as the following,

> [image]

Given a basis $\bf{V}$, define the inner product matrix as the following,

> [image]

$\bf{V}$ is an orthonormal basis if its inner product matrix with respect to the inner product $<>$ is an identity matrix.

The Gram-Schmidt process guarantees the existence of an orthonormal basis with respect to $<>$ for any inner product $<>$.

> [image]

My question is, **how about symmetric orthonormal basis** (suppose V is a vector space over field $F$, or just look at vector space $\Bbb R^n$)? Can we always find an symmetric orthonormal basis for any inner product $<>$? Thank you!

Comment: What's a symmetric basis?

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question.  We can just deal with $\Bbb R^n$. Treat a basis as a non-singular $n \times n$ matrix. For any inner product, does it always exist a symmetric orthonormal basis? For example, for the standard inner product, the identity matrix is a symmetric orthonormal basis.

Comment: Yes, for the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the bilinear form can be represented by the identity matrix.  However if you fix that basis, which one must do to talk about matrix representations, then not all inner products are going to represented by orthogonal matrices (columns forming an additional orthonormal basis).  The matrix representations will, however, always be symmetric (by virtue of the symmetry of the real inner product).

Comment: What is your reference?